# ONVIF: Which wsdl files are needed for Profile S

Tags: c++, gsoap, onvif

I am trying to write an ONVIF client in C++ using gsoap. The executable wsdl2h will generate the needed header and the rest I think I understand.

My question:

Which wsdl files will I need, if I want my client to work with a device that supports ONVIF Profile S (let's say the mandatory specs)? Most importantly, how do I find that out? Is there a one-to-one link? Also, because I am behind a proxy and I can't seem to get that to work, can I somehow download all the needed wsdl files in a bunch?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list of .wsdl files I found...

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/event.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl/media.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/recording.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/display.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/receiver.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl

https://onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/search.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/replay.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/advancedsecurity/wsdl/advancedsecurity.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl/imaging.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/analyticsdevice.wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/thermal/wsdl/thermal.wsdl

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There is not a WSDLfile that automatically includes all the WSDL files you may need.

If you check the [ONVIF Profile S page](https://www.onvif.org/profiles/profile-s/), you will find the [Profile S specification](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/ONVIF_Profile_-S_Specification_v1-1-1.pdf). As you can see from the PDF, there are some functions that are mandatory for a client to be conformant, others are conditional mandatory (you have to implement them if you want to claim support for those features) and some are optional.

After you choese what you want to support, you need to include the WSDL files for the services that you must implement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I know which wsdl file corresponds to a specific function?

Comment: each function belongs to a service, and each service has a dedicated WSDL file.

Comment: where is this service file found?

Comment: ONVIF specifications are available here: https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications/